# Listing all nested user controls from a master page on page load

Tags: c#, asp.net

On page load is there a way to enumerate all the nest user controls for that specific page load?

I'd like to be able to enumerate all the user controls that implement an interface, and call the interface method for the controls before asp.net passes control to thier page_load events.

The problem is from the master page level, any page in the app could be loading, and each of them could have any random user control, and I need the type reference to determine if they implement the interface, and to call the method.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: why do you need to do so before the page_load ?

Comment: The database performance is rather low, and I'm trying to rewrite the data access to run asynch on parrallel background threads, then have call backs into each user control to supply the data when as it comes back from the database. In order to do this I need to know as many of the data requests as possible to try to get as much done together as I can, this requires finding the user controls and asking them what data they need, and a call back address.  The point is to improve the performance with as little changes to the app as possible, this is my first experiment into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would something like this work?

```
void ProcessControls(Control control)
{
    if(control is IMyInterface) //whatever your interface name is
    {
        (control as IMyInterface).MethodName();
    }

    foreach(Control child in control.Controls)
    {
        ProcessControls(child);
    }
}
```

Comment: My first attempt looked almost word for word like this, but it would never find the controls at runtime.

Comment: Not sure what I did wrong the first time, but tried this again and it worked perfectly this time. Thanks!